# Comment accorder le participe passé « aidé(e) » avec un pronom ?

Tags: pronoms, accord, participe-passé

Si une femme parle et qu'elle dit par exemple :

> Vous ne m'avez pas **aidée**.

Est-ce correct d'écrire cela ainsi ? Ou faudrait-il plutôt écrire :

> Vous ne m'avez pas **aidé**.

Answer (score 4):

Le complément d'objet direct **m'** est placé **avant** le verbe **avoir** donc accord en genre et en nombre:

> Vous ne m'avez pas **aidée**